# How Would I replace a string if its input in a certain order?

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
var xboxConverter = {
  "1" : "Up",
  "2" : "Down",
  "3" : "Down Foward",
  "4" : "Backward",
  "5" : "Standing",
  "6" : "Forward",
  "7" : "Up Backward",
  "8" : "Up",
  "9" : "Up Foward",
  "236S": "Quarter Circle Special",
  ",": "  ",
  "H" : "B",
  "M": "Y",
  "L": "X",
  "S": "A",
  "2" : "Down",
  "RB" : "RB",
  "236" : "Quarter Circle Forward",
  "214" : "Quarter Circle Backwards",
  "214S" : "Quarter Circle Backwards Special",

};

document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const input = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  const inputValidated = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,]/g, "");
  const arrOfIns = inputValidated.split(" ");
  const arrOfOuts = arrOfIns.map((e) =>
    xboxConverter[e] ? xboxConverter[e] : ""    
  ); 
if (parseInt.innerText == 236 & 214)
return
  const out = arrOfOuts.join(" , ");
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = out;

});
```

To better describe what I mean if someone inputs 236 together it should say "Quarter Circle Forward" or if they input 236RT it should say "Quarter Circle Forward Right Trigger".

Comment: you'll need to parse the string from longest keys to shortest to start, but also `out` is just a string, so `out.input` doesn't make any sense.

Comment: Im trying to learn javascript

Comment: Never mind it works but I would have to type out every  string   "214S" : "Quarter Circle Backwards Special", is there anyway to make this easier where they can just type 214A and it displays  "Quarter Circle Backwards Special" or for example something that isnt coded in 214H which would display  "Quarter Circle Backwards Heavy"but without needing to code every string like that out?

Comment: How does an input of "236" output "Quarter Circle Forward"? I though its "Quarter Circle".

Comment: well then what would 214 be? 214 indicates Quarter Circle Backwards.

Comment: "Quarter Circle Backwards"? You mean you need to output the value according to the key that the user inputs?

Comment: That's what im trying to achieve. So noobs can better learn combos it will eventually be converted for every controller. From Fightsticks.

Comment: I'm not sure how you'd handle the difference between 236S (Down Down Forward Forward A) and 236S (Quarter Circle Special), or are multiple commands separated by spaces?

Comment: That is a problem as well.

Answer (score -1):

From your comments, I can understand that you are looking for a value matching the key that the user inputs. You can simply check for it without any splits and for loops like:

```js
var xboxConverter = {
  "1": "Up",
  "2": "Down",
  "3": "Down Foward",
  "4": "Backward",
  "5": "Standing",
  "6": "Forward",
  "7": "Up Backward",
  "8": "Up",
  "9": "Up Foward",
  "236S": "Quarter Circle Special",
  ",": "  ",
  "H": "B",
  "M": "Y",
  "L": "X",
  "S": "A",
  "2": "Down",
  "RB": "RB",
  "236": "Quarter Circle Forward",
  "214": "Quarter Circle Backwards",
  "214S": "Quarter Circle Backwards Special",

};

document.querySelector("textarea").addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  const input = e.target.value.toUpperCase();
  const inputValidated = input.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ,]/g, "");
  document.getElementById("output").innerText = xboxConverter[inputValidated] ? xboxConverter[inputValidated] : "No data";
});
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Is this what you're looking for?

Comment: No not quite. I need i to show "Quarter Circle Forward even if they input 2, 3, 6, instead of 236